# Purpose of function(data){} in JQuery $.get()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

In my MySQL database there is a column for VideoID and VideoCode

I have a PHP function in **backend.php** that aims to pick the next video in the list as follows:

```
$VideoID = 0;

function nextvideo(){
    global $VideoID;
    $VideoID = $VideoID + 1;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE VideoID = '".$VideoID."'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    return $result[2];
}

$VideoCode = nextvideo();
```

I then have the `$VideoCode` variable `echo` in my front end file inside a url that gives the embedded video.

That is all fine and it works, each time the `nextvideo()` function is called it picks the next `$VideoCode` correctly. However I want to implement a 'next' button that allows the user to effectively call the `nextvideo()` function and therefore load the next video. So I know i need to use AJAX and the `.get()` function but I have no idea how to use it and have tried reading up on it. So far I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function next() {
      $.get("backend.php", *1*, *2*);
      return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="next();">Next</a>
```

I know that after **backend.php** in the `$.get()` function i need some more info, `*1*` being something to send to the backend file and `*2*` being what to do with the result once its sent back. This is where I am stuck.

Does `*1*` need to be `nextvideo()` because that's the PHP function i wish to call, then `*2*` be something that will refresh the page so that the `$VideoCode` variable is updated and the next video is updated? Reading the documentation i know it needs to look something like:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

But what is `function(data)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function(data)` is a javascript function which is called when the request completes, passing in the variable `data` which is the page returned from the server. So in other words, when the request completes the code in that function will be executed and the variable `data` will contain whatever the server sent back from your request.

What you want to do is something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function next() {
     var currentVideoId = $('#videoId').val();
     $.get("backend.php", { videoId: currentVideoId }, function(data) {
        $('#video').html(data); 
        $('#videoId').val($('#videoId').val() + 1);
     });
     return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="next();">Next</a>
```

Where you have a hidden input field with id `videoId` which has a value of the current video's id and an element with id `video` which is the element to be updated with the new video.

Your PHP script would look something like this:

```
$VideoID = intval($_GET['videoId']) + 1;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE VideoID = '".$VideoID."'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $result[2];
```

This accepts the $_GET variable being passed in by the AJAX function and prints out the video code which is sent to the `data` variable in the javascript.

Hopefully this helps, if you're still unsure of anything please ask!

Comment: @DavidT The `#` is a jquery selector, which translates to 'select element with id x', so `$('#video')` selects the element on the page with the `id` attribute `video`. The javascript on the page increments the hidden counter within the page so that if the next button is clicked a second time it doesn't load the same video as the previous time the button was clicked. Right now the AJAX just calls the entire `backend.php` file, but you can put all of the next video PHP code in this `if` if you want it only to run on this ajax call `if(isset($_GET['videoId'])`

Comment: @DavidT When the PHP script runs (having been called by $.get()), anything that is printed to the page is sent to the `data` variable in the function embedded within the `$.get()` function. Right now what it's set to do is to find an element with the id `video` and set the HTML within it to whatever is in that `data` variable. So when the PHP script finishes running whatever was echoed in the PHP script is inserted into that element. If you want to see the request and the page is being sent back, watch the "Network" tab in the chrome developer tools when you fire off the request.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature is :

```
jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

`url` : The url you want to make a "get" http request to. It could be an html file, a plain text file, an image, etc.. In your case, it is a php file that will execute itself entirely every time you call it.

`[data]` : optional parameter , the data you want to send with your request, in the form of key - values pairs. For example you could send , with your request : { id : 1 } , which your server (php script in that case) would receive and could use to serve the appropriate response to your client (your javascript in that case)

`[success]` : optional parameter , the callback function to be executed once the server has answered. It is an optional parameter, but you will , most probably, always want to do something once the server has done it's job and served you a response.

In the example you provided :

```
function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data)
};
```

is an anonymous function (is not named). When executed, that function will receive up to 3 parameters:  `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`. We are interested in the data sent back from the server. It can be anything : text, xml , html , json etc. Since it is only an example on the jquery documentation website, the function only alert(annoying message box from the browser) the data it received, and does really nothing useful with it. I'm not really sure I understand what you want to do in your specific case, but I hope my general answer will help you.